# Node.js moongoose convert to spring mongotemplate

Tags: node.js, spring, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation

> I have a code like this created with node.js and mongoose:

```
let data = { buy: [], sell: [] };
let buy = await Orders.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      status: "Open",
      instrument: instrument,
      bidType: "buy",
    },
  },
  { $group: { _id: "$price", amount: { $sum: "$amount" } } },
  { $sort: { _id: -1 } },
  { $limit: 100 },
]);
```

> I want to do this using springboot and mongodb. I tried many ways but couldn't.I will be
> grateful if you could help me

Comment: can you share what you have tried, what issue you are facing?

Comment: I tried: MongoOperation,MongoTemplate, @Annotation, Qurey etc. There is no error but I couldn't find the right way.